# Pybind11 doesn't work or C++ doesn't compile after upgrading to Mojave: -lstdc++ not found

Tags: c++, macos-mojave, pybind11

I was able to install the pybind11 example [here](https://github.com/pybind/python_example) before I upgraded my MacOS. However, after I upgraded my MacOS to Mojave, when I compile the same example on that link, I see the following error:

```
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

Am I missing a linker command? I've searched online but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you installed xcode and its command-line tools? I too work on Majave, but I experience no such problems

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually found the answer. I only needed to do

`export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9`

The installation went smoothly.